# is there some method to solve macros in glsl for vulkan

Tags: glsl, vulkan, spir-v

Many GLSL programs use macros

```
#ifdef
#else
#endif
```

to solve different configurations,  is there some elegant method to solve this issue when vulkan build pipeline layout and descriptor set?

Comment: Don't think so, if you want to change configurations dynamically it will have a performance penalty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using normal `if()\else()` blocks and Vulkan specialization constants should solve this one for most cases. I'd expect any sensible compiler to optimize out an entire `if()` basic block if the specialization constant is zero at compile time.